# Add colored noise to image (pink, blue, brown)

Tags: colors, noise, scikit-image

Can someone help me how I can add colored noise to image. I am using scikit-image but I don't find any kind of colored noise which I can generate using this library.

Comment: Do you mean pink/blue/brown as in the spectrum, or pink/blue/brown as in the colors?  Because for the latter you can generate noise using the provided methods, and then multiply it by the color itself.

Comment: I mean pink/blue/brown as in the spectrum. Then I want add it to image.

Comment: Do you have some idea of how that noise would be defined in 2D?  You may want something like: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5091-generate-spatial-data?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Thx but can u give me some example with numpy and scikit-image library in python?